# Redirect route with parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to redirect to the appropriate resource user when user wants to go to his profile.

Like this:

get 'profile', to: redirect("/users/#{ current_user.id }")

I don't know if it's possible

Comment: I guess you have already had a users controller, and you have already implemented "users#show" which makes it possible for users to view other user's profile. And you just want to reused "users#show" to show profile of the logged in user, right?

Comment: exactly it's totally this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after confirming your intention, since you have already had a users controller, and you have already implemented "users#show" which makes it possible for users to view other user's profile. I guess you can do it like this:

1. router

```rb
  get '/profile', to:"users#profile"
```

2. define profile action in your users controller, here there are two possible implementations (if you have already set the current login user to current_user variable)

a) not redirect, just render the show action with required variables

```
def profile
  @user = current_user
  render :action => "show" # if your show function is only depends on @user variable
end
```

b) redirect

```
def profile
  redirect_to action: "show", id: current_user.id
end
```

Comment: Perfect ! (I take the option b) ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Make your routes

```
match 'profile' => 'users#show', :via => :get
```

in your show action

```
@user = current_user
```

this will help to create the profile page of the user

Comment: ok the problem is that I have this:  before_action :set_user, only: %i[show edit update destroy]  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

Comment: change to`@user = current_user`

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting user to an URL like `/users/#{ current_user.id }` for their profile page is not recommended. It could be an [IDOR](https://www.owasp.org/images/4/4a/IDOR.pdf) if you don't have user authorization in that endpoint(i.e, checking if the user id in the URL is for current user only)

Having said this, you can try @abhishek's answer to handle show action